# Bootstrap: how to align and center buttons at the bottom of equal-height columns

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, multiple-columns

I have a three-column layout using Bootstrap 4 columns (col-sm).  See codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EryRJL?editors=1100

I have some text in a paragraph in each column, and a button below the paragraph.  How can I align all the buttons vertically at the bottom of the columns, while centering them in their respective columns?

I can push the buttons to the bottom with

```
.button-container {
    width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

But then the centering doesn't work because width: 100% shifts the div to the right due to column padding.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out thanks to [this snippet](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/401AW).  Instead of `width: 100%`, I simply needed `left: 0` and `right: 0` to fit the container properly.